# What is the difference between mySQLi (myPhpAdmin) and SQLite (for Android database)?

Tags: android, database

What is the difference between mySQLi (PhpMyAdmin) and SQLite (for Android database)?

Please tell me both Application (software) difference and coding difference...

Comment: mostly coding difference

Comment: Please elaborate... i could find any particular answer on Google, that is why i am disturbing you all on StackOverFlow :'(

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. If you have a completely new and unrelated question, then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Edit old questions to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

They're different storage engines. MySQL is a fully fledged enterprise level database, each database and table is usually split out into multiple files which contain things such as the actual table data, as well as indexes and caches. MySQL is designed for huge database application and data processing from multiple clients.

MySQLi is just the PHP MySQL connector library to establish a DB connection and query the MySQL DB from PHP.

PhpMyAdmin is just a web gui to manage your MySQL database through PHP.

Sqlite isn't specific to Android, but its a small lightweight single file database which is designed for embedded application database. This is more for lightweight simple application data storage.

Answer (score 0):

MySqli is enterprise or server based database while sqllite is small database used within application